# Product of two Ornstein Uhlenbeck processes : conditional distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

*Disclaimer: [I asked this question in Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485190/product-of-two-ornstein-uhlenbeck-processes-conditional-distribution), but I realise it's very relevant over here as well. I don't know how to link the two.*

Let $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ be two independent OU processes (each with some fixed correlation time-scale), and let $S(t) = X(t)Y(t)$. Then is there a expression for the conditional distribution of $X(t)$ given that you observe $S(t)$ till time $t$ -- i.e.  $P\left(X\left(t\right)\left|\left\{ S\left(t'\right)\right\} _{t'<t}\right.\right)$ ?

What about the case when $X$ is just a Gaussian random variable independent of $Y(t)$?

Comment: Just an annotation: the OU process is Gaussian, so IIRC the moments of the product have closed form.